# Relative clause ending with a noun should be followed by の or である? What is the difference?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

According to the book I am reading now, a relative clause ending with noun must be followed by の. But sometimes I also find a relative clause ending with noun that is followed by である.

Consider the following examples:

> A: 両親が日本人**の**学生はクラスの２０％をしめている。
>
> B: 両親が日本人**である**学生はクラスの２０％をしめている。

Literally it means

> The students whose parents are Japanese constitute 20% of the students in the class.

## Questions

- When do we have to use の and である for a relative clause ending with a noun?
- Is there any difference in nuance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When do we have to use の and である for a relative clause ending with a noun?

The general tendency, if not the absolute rule, is that it would sound less formal and more conversational if you used 「の」.

(Grammatically speaking, this 「の」 is ***appositional***.)

「である」 would make the sentence sound more formal and/or academic. In any kind of formal speech or writing, you would use 「である」 in that example sentence.

> Is there any difference in nuance?

The only difference in nuance is the level of formality as discussed above.

Comment: @virmaior Thanks for pointing that out.  I have edited the last part of my answer.